# Is cleint side rendering of huge data with dc for interactive vizualization is suitable for analytics tools

Tags: python, dashboard, interactive, crossfilter

To develop a interactive dashboard like https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/vc/index.html with [DC](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/), is client side rendering on the whole dataset with crossfilter is best option for an analytics platform?

Some insight on analytics platform - a platform which can connect to any database tables residing anywhere on the world upon providing the database connection details and fetch the columns of a specific table for analysis(summation,average,minimum,maximum) ans then render them with charting library for visualization on client side.

I know there is a possible way with server side (NodeJS) rendering, one can leverage the crossfilter library, But as a backend the plan is to use Python.

Main concern- The interaction should be smooth on client side even when the data size is huge. Now the questions are:

- Is it a good idea to fetch all the data in client side regardless of its size to make the app most interactive?
- How much limitation does it impose on client memory stack?
- Is there any better way to do it so we don't have to trade off between interactivity and client/server side processing of data?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it a good idea to fetch all the data in client side regardless of
>   its size to make the app most interactive?

No

> How much limitation does it impose on client memory stack?

As big as your data. Chrome maxes out around 1GB of memory consumption, but is going to grind to a halt long before you get there for most use-cases. If you have more than ~10MB of data compressed, it is time to start thinking about non-client-side options.

> Is there any better way to do it so we don't have to trade off between
>   interactivity and client/server side processing of data?

You'll need to think about advanced architectures that shares the load of data processing between the client and the server, which generally don't have a simple library implementation available. I put together http://lcadata.info (it's open source) as one example of how to do this. It's Lift/Scala/Spark on the back-end, but you could do something similar with Python.